# Помогите разобраться с OAuth

Tags: oauth, openid

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь построить схему аутентификации пользователя на своём сервисе привлекая в качестве гаранта например Google. Как я понимаю можно зарегистрироваться у Гугла для получения данной услуги и получить от него "пару ключей". Дальше всё в тумане.
Основная цель: удостовериться на моём сервисе, что пользователь тот за кого себя выдаёт.
Мой сервис - это совокупность Android приложения и сервера выполняющего роль облачка для хранения настроек пользователя.
Я не хочу реализовывать механизм авторизации у себя и регистрации пользователей. Хочется запросить у пользователя его Google Account E-Mail и получить от Google подтверждение что это тот самый пользователь, а не кто-то другой. Вот только не могу собрать всю эту кашу воедино. Уже голова распухла.

Подскажите пожалуйста как должно быть и возможно ли это.

Comment: какие у вас технологии используются?

Comment: А какие нужно? Вот и изучаю чтобы понять какие нужно. Хотелось бы ограничиться REST HTTP

Comment: Ну, я имею ввиду стек, язык, устройство.

Comment: Да без разницы - полиглоты мы. Вообще со строны Android что же ещё как не Java или KT, со стороны сервера PHP backend.

Comment: Ну я не экстрасенс, чтобы узнать, что у вас сервер + Android

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: начать необходимо с данной документации, создать простые приложения, которые предлагаются в данных гайдах

Comment: Ну экстрасенс не экстрасенс, но об этом так то сразу было описано. Нет?

Comment: Прошу прощения, перечитал внимательно, действительно.

Comment: Как уже написал ниже, не понятно в каком месте МОЙ СЕРВЕР может удостовериться, что авторизация пользователя у Гугла валидна и ему - пользователю, можно верить.

Comment: клиент отправляет на сервер логин пароль, сервер генерирует запрос со своим ключом, зарегистрированным у гугла, далее гугл возвращает ответ, является ли пользователь зарегистрированным. Если в ответе вернулся успешный код исполнения, можно запрашивать у гугла данные о пользователе

Comment: А на сервер ли он отправляет? На сколько я понял из схемы клиент общается логином и паролем непосредственно с Гуглом.
Ну запросил данные о пользователе у Гугла. Как это поможет теперь в общении с моим сервером? Пускай есть теперь данные о пользователе, как моему серверу быть уверенным, что они верны и это не подстава?

Comment: Обычно авторизовывается только одно приложение (непосредственно сервер), оно хранит секретный ключ, своего рода пароль, доступный только ему, через него авторизуется на гугле и запрашивает свои данные. Вам же нужно проверить, что пользователь, который использует ваше клиентское приложение, может использовать ваш сервер, так как он зарегистрирован через сервис гугл, так?

Comment: Именно. Думалось что возможно таким путём пойти...

Comment: ну, так и надо же

Comment: не понятно как это обеспечивает какую-то безопасность на промежутке между Android приложение - мой сервер. Пускай Android приложение КАК-ТО сообщило моему СЕРВЕРУ от чьего имени пользователь хочет выполнять действия. Мой сервер пообщался с Гуглом и договорился о чём-то. Но как моему серверу верить Android приложению? Что должно происходить на этом этапе? Как Android приложение передаёт моему серверу явки для аутентификации у Гугла через меня?

Comment: Access token, он отправляется клиенту, клиент в каждом запросе его посылает на сервер, а сервер с помощью него общается с гуглом. Access Token выдаётся только на время, его необходимо постоянно обновлять

Comment: Как-то так и виделось, но особо легче не стало. т.е. на каждый приход токена от клиента я должен свериться с Гуглом, что он всё ещё валиден? Ну ведь он может быть отменён или перевыпущен раньше срока жизни?

Answer (score 1):

**Oauth**

> [Oauth](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) - открытый протокол авторизации, который позволяет
> предоставить третьей стороне ограниченный доступ к защищённым ресурсам
> пользователя без необходимости передавать ей (третьей стороне) логин и
> пароль

На текущий момент существует 2 версии протокола OAuth 1.0 и OAuth 2.0 (про различия можно прочитать в [этой статье](https://hueniverse.com/introducing-oauth-2-0-b5681da60ce2?gi=80166546d9aa) ). Сейчас большинство использует Oauth 2.0 и google не искючение, поэтому стоит рассмореть именно эту версию.

**Принцип работы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*User* - **владелец ресурса**, который авторизирует пользователя через свое приложение.

*Client* - собственно Ваше приложение.

*Resource Server* - На сервере ресурсов размещаются защищенные учетные записи пользователей.

Authorization Server - сервер авторизации проверяет пользователя из сервера ресурсов, а затем выдает маркеры доступа к приложению.

- `Приложение` запрашивает **авторизацию пользователя** для доступа к `ресурсам сервиса`,
- ЕСЛИ пользователь авторизовался, `Приложение` получает **разрешение авторизации**
- И запрашивает **токен доступа** к `серверу авторизации` (API), по идентификации пользователя и разрешение на авторизацию.
- ЕСЛИ идентификация `приложения` и разрешение авторизации является действительным, `сервер авторизации` (API) **выдает маркер доступа к приложению**. Авторизация завершена.
- Приложение запрашивает **ресурс** (Ваша функция колбек) у `сервера ресурсов` (API) и **представляет токен доступа** для аутентификации.
- Если токен доступа действителен, сервер ресурсов (API) передает ресурс приложению.

---

Более детальное описание в [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

---

**Goolge Auth 2.0**

Из [описания](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?hl=en_US) следует:

1. Нужно получить/создать Credentials (доступы).

   1.1 Создать список доступных доменов + верифицировать их на вкладке Domain Verification (как это сделать можно узнать из [статьи](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=ru))
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   1.2 создаем Oauth client Id
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   где указываем success URL вашего верифицированного ресурса. Например, `example.com/auth-callback`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В [руководстве](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?hl=en_US) на шаге 2 указано, что есть несколько способов получение доступа и они различаются в зависимости от типа приложения - это называется **user consent**. И оно разруливается уже Вашим кодом. Как это сделать описано [тут](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth).

Там описано 4 шага: создание параметров авторизации и редирект на страницу авторизации гугла. Кстати тут можно воспользоваться google библиотеками для авторизации.

На третьем шаге пользователь решает давать приложению доступы к учетной записи (этим занимается сторона гугла). Ну и наконец на четвертом шаге к Вам в auth-callback должен передаться положительный или отрицательный результат

**если ошибка**

```
https://oauth2.example.com/auth?error=access_denied
```

**если все авторизация прошла**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&
 access_type=offline&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Fcallback&
 response_type=code&
 client_id=client_id
```

Вообщем это все по авторизации, далее работа с АПИ гугл и 4-й пункт обновление токена.

Comment: это всё замечательно. Не понятно до сих пор одно, может ли гугл в таком случае выступать просто гарантом аутентификации для работы уже со сторонним ресурсом? Как сторонний ресурс понимает, что аутентификация валидна?

Comment: В момент когда вы нажимаете на кнопку "Войти через ГУГЛ" вы делаете **редирект** на сервер авторизации гугла https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth+ГЕТ ПАРМЕТРЫ, сервер гугла определяет авторизирован  пользователь или нет, а по гет параметрам проводит авторизацию вашего ресурса. Потом уже сервер гугла делает редирект обратно  на специальный урл который Вы указали при регистрации сервиса. Например, test.com/auth2google

Comment: А второй раз? Когда уже есть токен якобы полученный ранее, как проверить что он ещё жив?

Comment: Второй раз отправляете запрос middleware "авторизирован ли кто"

Comment: Когда заходим смотрим есть ли токен, если есть, делаем запрос авторизации, если нет, то делает редирект на сервер авторизации гугла, если токен валидный, то авторизирован

Comment: В андроиде я не очень, но как пример есть статья http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/oauth.php

Comment: В результате проб и ошибок я получил JWT. Он содержит нужный мне email и это хорошо. Но как теперь с его помощью авторизироваться на моём сервере? Нужно отправить весь этот JWT в REST запросе до сервера, а сервер должен проверить по своему каналу его валидность?

Comment: Проверять по идее надо только один раз - когда заходишь в приложение. При заходе в приложение нужно [аутентифицировать пользователя](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code).

Comment: И что это даёт. Как МОЕМУ backend'у понять что данный JWT "верный" а не херня какая-нить?

Comment: Когда пользователь заходит в приложение, он всегда должен получать токен 1 раз и до того момента как не выйдет. И должен сохранятся на бэке, идентифицировать по токену это уже задача вашего бэка

Comment: То есть получили токен, передали на бэк и, например, в редисе сохранили токен + клиентИд.

Comment: и второй запрос уже проверяет права по ид клиента и токену

Comment: мне не понятно почему я не могу состряпать какой угодно токен и "первый" раз его отправить на сервер как "настоящий". Как серверу понять что токен "настоящий"? Где это написано?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87552/discussion-between-kostiantyn-okhotnyk-and-spider).

Comment: oauth2callback.php в $_SESSION['access_token'] устанавливается токен из $client->getAccessToken();
а в getAccessToken он попадает когда вызывается $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
а authenticate (github.com/googleapis/…) под капотом получает креды из `$creds = $auth->fetchAuthToken($httpHandler);`, `fetchAuthToken` по идее делает запрос к гуглу
вот поэтому подделать нельзя. Так работает на php. То есть на сервера в калбеке идет  на гугл апи и оттуда получаем токен

Comment: Вам понятно немного стало ? :)